# Simple pricing example confusion

Tags: option-pricing, arbitrage, pricing, risk-neutral-measure

This it taken from "Heard on the Street", Section B.

> Consider a market with $0$ risk-free rate, no transactions costs etc. The IBM stock costs \$75 and does not pay dividends. Design a security which pays \$1 if IBM stock reaches \$100. What does it cost?

The answer is \$.75 which can be proved by no-arbitrary considerations. At the same time, risk-neutral pricing suggests that the price is
$$
  \mathsf P\{\text{IBM has hit \$100 at least once}\} = 1.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it the question does not enforce that the market is free of arbitrage. This is why you can get to contradicting prices. Thus you can't actually apply a risk-neutral argument here without making additional assumptions.

You yourself provide the example of such an arbitrage. If the underlying process had a B&S dynamics you could just borrow money for free, buy the stock and wait until it hits the $100 mark.

Seeing how one does not know the dynamics of the underlying process it makes sense to enter into the static hedge of holding 0.75 of the stock.

**Related Question:** [Price Option and find replicating portfolio](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10338/price-an-option-and-find-a-replicating-portfolio/10384#10384)

Comment: I think I see your point: when we are making an equivalent change of measure, we have to restrict ourselves to finite intervals of time, otherwise changing the drift changes the null events. Thanks

Comment: Price this derivative in the digital framework. This will allow the same logic to be implied such as cash-or-nothing options. You could price in the barrier framework as well specifying a few extra parameters within the BS methodology. These methods will allow the security to be priced under the risk neutral measure implying a martingale.